# Access permissions during android file sharing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-file, android-sharing

Why is it sufficient to [openFileOutput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) a file with mode [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) (as the manual [says](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content)) to make a file readable by other apps (via a share Intent)?

Even if the *file* is readable, doesn't the *directory* remain private (rwx------ rather than rwxrwxrwx)?

Comment: Useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957679/access-to-mode-world-readable-files-in-application-private-directory-on-android/14257260#14257260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if the file is readable, doesn't the directory remain private (rwx------ rather than rwxrwxrwx)?

Having the directory be deny-all would prevent third parties from listing the contents of the directory or creating new files there. It has no impact on being able to read a file given a fully-qualified path to that file.

That being said, please do not use `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`. [Use `FileProvider` instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), so you have finer-grained control over who has access to that content. That way, for example, you can have the file be completely inaccessible *except* for a specific share operation.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that I understand you. I was referring to the second option ("Write the data to a file in your own application directory") at http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content . But you suggest instead that the fifth solution ("Store the data in your own ContentProvider") is a better one. If the file in question is merely an exported file, and it will be deleted after the share completes, would you still suggest that the fifth solution is better than the (simpler) second?

Comment: @Calaf: "If the file in question is there merely an exported file, and it will be deleted after the share completes, would you still suggest that the fifth solution is better than the (simpler) second?" -- bear in mind that you have no idea when "the share completes". It could take seconds; it could take days. You simply are not informed if the user did or did not "share" it or when the "sharing" will take place. You will need to keep the file around for what your users feel is a reasonable period of time, which may be longer than you are thinking.

Comment: @Calaf: I would use `FileProvider` over `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` regardless, but the value of the additional security climbs with each millisecond that the file is available to miscreants.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the manual cite is incorrect. Files in internal storage can't be read by other apps, regardless of their mode. The confusion you're having is not uncommon, which is why apps should use a FileProvider to offer files to other apps.

It's a matter of security: file system permissions do not adequately protect data. To offer a file to another app via file permissions, you have to set the equivalent of chmod a+r (at the minimum). That gives read access to *any* other app, which is an invitation to any Tom, Dick, or Harry to start slurping your files. Moreover, the access change is permanent, unless you remember to change it back.

In comparison, using URI permissions with a FileProvider offers temporary read access only, and only to the specific app that requested it. You can set up your app so that you only grant access if the user comes to your app to request the file; at least then, the user knows both the app that asked for the file and the app that had it.

Comment: "Files in internal storage can't be read by other apps, regardless of their mode." I see that MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated, but doesn't running it (however unkosher) mean precisely that it is implemented via a chmod a+r? If indeed the directory remains chmod a+x (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14257260/704972  cited by Pietu1998 above)—in other words, the files within can be accessed only if their name is known—then none of Tom,  Dick, or Harry has access unless they find out first the filename. And even then, they can read it but not overwrite.

Comment: "Files in internal storage can't be read by other apps, regardless of their mode." Untrue at least for most of the current installed base.  "To offer a file to another app via file permissions, you have to set the equivalent of chmod a+r" that's exactly what the mode setting does.

Comment: @Calaf - you are basically correct, but assuming that nobody can guess the filename is risky.  In particular, an app that's even going to try to access and exploit something may well be specifically targeting the data files of a given app, and thus have been written utilizing knowledge obtained by decompiling/studying the targeted app.